# theArray is not defined

Tags: javascript

I try to avoid to use $.grep to filter what needs to be filter. In my case I want to remove array of objects which has an id of '123', but I'm getting theArray is not defined error.

```
    function filter(array, conditionFunction) {
      var validValues = [];
      for (var index = 0; index < array.length; i++) {
        if (conditionFunction(theArray[index])) {
          validValues.push(theArray[index]);
        }
      }
    }

    var cart = [
  {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "banana",
    "image": "56fca57eb239dc38e355c86b-1459398061689-2013-Le-Tour-de-Langkawi-Stage-5-3.jpg",
    "price": 12,
    "discount_price": 8,
    "qty": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Christ come",
    "image": "56fcb471b239dc38e355c86c-1459401869191-klcc.jpg",
    "price": 12.9,
    "discount_price": 11.9,
    "qty": 4
  }
]
    cart = filter(cart, function(e) {
      return e.id !== '123';
    });

    console.log(cart);
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be defined? The argument's name is `array`, not `theArray`. Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask). You're expected to make more of an effort than this to debug the issue before posting a question.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error message into your question so we can see the full detail?

Comment: and your function doesn't return anything, so `cart` will also be `undefined` at the bottom

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use the function given here http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/utils/

Answer (score 0):

This ought to fix your problem. You changed your `array` variable to be `theArray` in the middle of your `for-loop`. Javascript can't know that, so you'll have to be more supportive and tell JS which array you mean.

```
for (var index = 0; index < array.length; i++) {
   if (conditionFunction(array[index])) {
      validValues.push(array[index]);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's part of it, not all of it, but frankly this question doesn't need answering. It needs closing and deleting.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/utils/ find theArray here.